# Excel move or copy with reference to another sheet in destination workbook

Tags: excel

I have a template which i use and then copy into multiple clients workbooks, the template sheet is called "Returns 2014" and in cell A1 of the template i have a formulae =NotesA1! , when i make a copy of this sheet and move it to another workbook i require that formulae in A1 to remain as =NotesA1! and to pull that data from the destination workbook instead, the formulae changes when i copy it to pull from the template workbooks Notes A1 instead od destination workbooks. How can i get around this?

Answer (score 0):

Surely the formula is

=Notes!A1

and does not have the ! sign at the end. In any case, after the copy operation, the formula will be

=[TemplateFileName]Notes!A1

Run a find/replace and replace the "[TemplateFileName]" with nothing. Make sure to look in formulas, not just values.